# Convert Highcharts dateformat to notmal readable using python

Tags: pandas, highcharts, python-3.6, python-3.5

I want to convert Highcharts date formatted value "1532059200000" to normal readable date format,
Conversion above date will look like this : july 20, 2018
How to convert above value to normal date format using python

Comment: Assume your value is in a `time` column: `df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"],unit="ms")`.

Comment: actually i text mined this value from web

Comment: Hi @shyamrag cp, That value is a timestamp in milliseconds. Please check this thread: https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/442320-converting-milliseconds-human-time to find out how to convert it to other format.